# Mac Monterey - bash - .bash_profile Terminal error message

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, path

I am running bash (instead of zsh, which is going to be the default shell, apparently, for MacOS in the future) so certain scripts can run, such as yt_dlp, which apparently won't run in zsh. I have a copy of terminal up and running on login. I kept seeing the error: -bash (my .bash_profile PATH here) No such file or directory. That path is:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

I took references to all folders out, leaving just

```
/usr/local/bin
```

No error. Added /bin

```
/usr/local/bin:/bin
```

Got that 'No such file or directory' error again. I had a look for other path stuff, and found, in the /etc folder, a file called 'paths' with the following entry:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

So, I renamed my .bash_profile to .XXbash_profile and rebooted. The problem error no longer appeared in Terminal.

My question is: I'd like to enter a path for my Python3 install. Should I somehow add it to the 'paths' file (which has an attribute of 'locked') or to a new .bash_profile? I'll admit I'm a bit puzzled on the whole PATH thing.

I have looked up all the folders referenced in the .bash_profile argument: they all exist. I can access them all with 'cd /thatFolder'. So, the 'No such file or directory' cannot be with reference to any of those folders: they all exist and are accessible via 'cd'.

I cannot figure out what the 'No such file or directory' is with reference to. There are no extra spaces or mis-spelt folder names in that .bash_profile entry. Thank you for considering this little conundrum.

Comment: `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:$PATH"` — are you setting it as a variable do you just have that list of directories?

Comment: Tangential to your question but your login shell doesn't have to be Bash to run Bash scripts. Also, the Bash that ships with macOS is really old and may present compatibility problems with scripts expecting features only available in a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

When you're updating `PATH`, you shouldn't write the whole thing, just add the folder(s) you want to the front or back of it, e.g.

```
PATH=$PATH:/another/directory
```

or

```
PATH=/another/directory:$PATH
```

It mostly doesn't matter if you put it at the front or back, but if you have a directory that's supposed to supercede existing commands, you put it in front.

As long as your include the original default PATH you shouldn't get any errors when you try to run standard commands.

Comment: Quoting would not harm...

Comment: True, but in my experience it's not idiomatic in statements like this, since there's no word-splitting after expanding variables in assignments.

Comment: You're right, in this case it is not needed.